# PessimisticConcurrencyConflict Error While Operating On Azure Api Management Using Azure Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-api-management

Very recently I am observing random PessimisticConcurrencyConflict error while performing some operation on Api Management through Azure Powershell. The full error details given below:

**##[error]
Error Code: PessimisticConcurrencyConflict
Error Message: Operation on the API is in progress
Request Id: a9e7d42f-252c-492f-8b45-aeee836c4467
##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.**

For instances, I am sure nobody is using the api at that time. The error goes away upon retrying the same powershell.

So far I have observed this issue while using below command in Azure Powershell:

1. Creating a new Api Revision for an existing Api in Api Management by using

   `New-AzApiManagementApiRevision -Context $context -ApiId $APIId -ApiRevision $apiRevision -ApiRevisionDescription $apiRevisionDescription`
2. Importing from an api specification file to an existing Api in Api Management using

   `Import-AzApiManagementApi -Context $context -ApiId $apiId -ApiType Http -ApiRevision $apiRevision -Path $path -ServiceUrl $serviceUrl -SpecificationFormat Swagger -SpecificationPath "$SpecificationPath "`

Answer (score 0):

You can't do two concurrent operations at the same entity, APIM locks the entity you are updating/creating until the operation completes and then you can do another operation, you have to wait until the first operation to otherwise it returns the
pessimisticconcurrencyconflict error.

Comment: Pretty sure, not doing that.